# Differences between these 2 functions in solidity?

Tags: function, parameters, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I don't get the difference between these 2 functions in solidity, will the same result be returned?

```
address oldVoter;

  modifier checkSender(address actualVoter) {
        require(oldVoter != actualVoter);  
        _; 
    }


    function changeVote(address caller)public  {
        oldVoter =  caller;
    }


    function changeVote() public checkSender(msg.sender){
        olderVoter = caller;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this function is modified with `checkSender` modifier:

```
 function changeVote() public checkSender(msg.sender){
        olderVoter = caller;
    }
```

since it is modified you can see this function like this:

```
function changeVote() public checkSender(msg.sender){
        require(oldVoter != actualVoter); 
        // "_" in modifier is placeholder. saying that place the modified function here
        olderVoter = caller;
    }
```

There is another function with the same name `changeVote`, but if you notice it does not have any modifier and does not take any argument. It is absolutely legal to have the same function name with a different number of parameters of different data types for incoming parameters.

You can have multiple definitions for the same function name in the same scope in Solidity. This is called `function overloading`. The definition of the function must differ from each other by the types and/or the number of arguments in the argument list.  Return types are not taken into consideration for determining valid function signatures.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply, but what's the meaning checkSender(msg.sender)? is a way to check who's call the function?

Comment: @Mat msg.sender the one who calls the function. it is globally available in solidity

Comment: @Mat modifiers are special functions that can accept arguments

Comment: By including `checkSender(msg.sender) in your function's heading , every time the function is called, the `checkSender` modifier will be called with its `actualVoter` parameter set to `msg.sender`. You can include any checks you want inside the modifier, for example requiring that `oldVoter != actualVoter`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from your functions. `changeVote(address caller)` (first one) sets `oldVoter` to the `caller` input. The second one should not compile as `caller` is not defined it in.